# How can I encode post variables in Fiddler?

Tags: http, fiddler

It is clearly to me that when I [submit a simple form with](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/1966/) :

`a @ w+aaa`

Actually what is being posted is :

[image]

`html=a+%40+w%2Baaa`  (ignore the "html" word)

But when I post it via fiddler :

[image]

What is being submitted is `a @ w+aaa` ( the original raw string , obviously).

**Question:**

Can fiddler auto "encode" the variables so they will be sent as `a+%40+w%2Baaa` ?

Nb I know I can use the textwizard for this , but again , it is pretty annoying every time to open and paste values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler's Composer doesn't automatically encode variables for you, and no, there's no way that it could reliably do so, since there's no way to tell whether a given `=` or `&` is a part of the value, or a delimiter between values.

If you wanted, you could use the `WebForms` Inspector to compose the POST body; simply `SHIFT+Click` the Execute button and then use the WebForms Inspector to edit the body fields.

Comment: Eric, you said , "_use the WebForms Inspector to edit the body fields_"  —but it seems that I can't edit it http://i.imgur.com/b1pbOTl.png

Comment: You can only edit the content when the request is paused at a breakpoint, which is what happens when you `SHIFT+Click`.